# Sentencia Between no filtra por rango de fechas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 3 tablas

- producto
- factura_has_producto
- factura

Esta consulta funciona hasta cierto punto, me trae los 30 productos mas vendidos con sus respectivas unidades:

```
SELECT producto.nombre, SUM(factura_has_producto.cantidad) AS TotalVentas
FROM producto
INNER JOIN factura_has_producto
ON producto.idproducto = factura_has_producto.idproducto
INNER JOIN factura
ON factura.idfactura = factura_has_producto.idfactura
GROUP BY producto.nombre
ORDER BY SUM(factura_has_producto.cantidad) DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Hasta ahí bien
Pero ahora quiero que me filtre esa información entre un rango de fecha:

```
SELECT producto.nombre, SUM(factura_has_producto.cantidad) AS TotalVentas
FROM producto
INNER JOIN factura_has_producto
ON producto.idproducto = factura_has_producto.idproducto
INNER JOIN factura
ON factura.idfactura = factura_has_producto.idfactura
WHERE factura.fecha BETWEEN '01/01/2020' AND '28/06/2020'
GROUP BY producto.nombre
ORDER BY SUM(factura_has_producto.cantidad) DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Ya no me trae ningun resultado.

Comment: la segunda sentencia cuando agrego el rango de fechas no me trae resultados.

Comment: el tipo de datos fecha datetime

Comment: Es para ver el histórico de productos vendidos entre 2 fechas. Porque pueden haber fechas del año pasado.

Comment: Y si solo quiero ver indicadores del ultimo mes

Comment: Pues seria solo año mes y dia. nada mas. Se Muestra un calendario para escoger fechas a filtrar

Comment: Saludos. Poniéndolo como texto, la fecha debe ir como **año`-`mes`-`día**; el guión "`-`" es el separador.

Comment: Ejemplo: "WHERE factura.fecha BETWEEN '01/01/2020' AND '28/06/2020'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El esquema que le pasas a tu filtro en la columna `fecha` en la tabla `factura` no es el adecuado ya que:

- Mencionas es de tipo [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)
- El mismo de forma muy simplificada te va a pedir la sección de fecha o *DATE* de esta forma: **YYYY-MM-DD**
- Tu lo estás colocando personalizado en un formato que no coincide ni con el esquema esperado para la fecha ni con el tipo de dato que estás almacenando ya que seguirría haciendo falta el *tiempo*

Ahora el formato como tal para almacenar tus fechas es el adecuado, pero necesitamos indicar en el `SELECT` que solo considere la primer parte y descarte el resto. Para la tarea anterior, necesitamos de funciones de manejo de [tiempo y fechas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) descritas a detalle en la documentación.

En este caso quedaría:

```
WHERE DATE(factura.fecha) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-06-28'
```

Comment: Sí funcionó, muchas gracias el error era la escritura de fecha. Un saludo

Comment: @WeizmanCastañeda ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!